# CSS changes only show for the admins in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007

I'm trying to make a new site design and I'm using the "Band" theme&master.
I've made tons of changes to the css(the original one + made the page load another css to override some divs that can't change via the Band.css).

The changes show up to me and other 2 users who are also admins in the group.

but the rest of the organization just see the original Band.css and it's strange because I pretty much changed it.
I tried to add a CEWP that loads a different css but it doesn't even load it for them, just for me.

Oh and I made sure everything is Checked-In.

How can I make everyone see the changes?

Comment: Check the permissions for the style library, what permissions do your users have there? Are they in the "Style Resource Readers" group? Where did you place your custom files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are those files located?

You said you made sure that you have checked them in but
have you published it as a major version and approved them?

If not only administrators will see the changes because a normal user won't have the permission to see minor versions of your design.

Comment: OK now the users see major changes but still not completely like Admins do. For example I've made a new css file that should be loaded as well as the Band.css but for them it doesn't load(Not via CEWP and not via the custom css loading in the site settings where you can load one)

Comment: Have your tried to do a network trace in internet explorer to find if you might have a 400 (File not found) Error? Have you approved all files? Where is your design located. In which library?

Comment: In a library named "Style Library"

Comment: Can you go to the library and check the permission of a user that is not able to load the css? Are your users just "View Only" there?